# Connecting flight in Kuwait

Tags: visas, transit, iranian-citizens, kuwait, etihad

I bought a connecting flight with Etihad Airlines on the route from Tehran to Abu Dhabi. The first flight from Tehran to Kuwait is with Kuwait Airlines, and after seven hours, the second flight to Abu Dhabi is with Etihad Airways. I have an Iranian passport. Do I need a Kuwait transit visa?

Comment: Can you confirm that this is a single ticket or are these two separate tickets ?

Comment: It is single ticket

Comment: Sorry, another question: what is your citizenship and what passport/visa/documents are you planning on using ?